# Swift3 iOS -Firebase FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, credentials

I just upgraded my Firebase Cocoapods from 3.15.0 to 4.0.4 and FirebaseAuth Cocoapods from 3.1.1 to 4.0.0.

I'm using email & password to authenticate users. When a user changes their email I was using this method below and everything was working fine:

```
FIREmailPasswordAuthProviderID.credential(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!)
```

Now that I updated I get the error message

> Value of type 'String' has no member 'credential'

I looked on the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Constants#firemailpasswordauthproviderid) and it said to use the method below:

[image]

**The problem is I get the same exact error:**

```
FIREmailAuthProviderID.credential(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!)
```

> Value of type 'String' has no member 'credential'

**My original code below**

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

let user: User?

let credential = FIREmailPasswordAuthProviderID.credential(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!)

        if let user = user{
            user.reauthenticate(with: credential, completion: {
                (error) in
                if error != nil{
                    //...do something
                    return
                }
                //...do something else
            })
        }
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hold up

[FIREmailAuthProviderID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Constants#/c:@FIREmailAuthProviderID) is a constant that contains the auth providers id and is a string (which is EmailAuthProviderID in FB 4). There is no credential function which is why you are getting that error.

Here's a link to the [Firebase 4 Migration Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/naming-migration-guide)

The new format (and the correct function call) is

> EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail email: String, password:
>   String) -> AuthCredential

20171014 Edit: updated link to latest migration guide.

Comment: hey thanks for the help! I tried that last night and again just now and I got the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'EmailPasswordAuthProvider'

Comment: @LanceSamaria It's *EmailAuthProvider* not  *EmailPasswordAuthProvider*

Comment: The "link to the Firebase 4 changes" is broken. [Here's another list of release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this feature of fireBase however it appears that this link may be helpful

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIREmailAuthProvider

Comment: thanks for the help! I actually tried that method before i posted the question but it didn't work. Now that I think about it, it's the same method. I just looked at it and it's a class function. That's what I'm using in my code in the question

Comment: I was reading Firebase docs and there is a method for updating the user's email

Comment: user.updateEmail(to: "firebase_rox42@gmail.com") { error in
  // Check for error
}

Comment: is it possible to try
let credential = credential(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!)

Comment: I actually have that method somewhere else and it works fine. You can also update the password as in user.updatePassword but you need to verify that the other old email and password are correct before you allow them to update and that's where this method comes in because both pieces of info have to match. If they forgot their pw then I have an forgot password alert to help them. But the user should verify both to update either. Thanks 

Comment: I tried that earlier, it said it didn't know what credential was. I then tried it .credential(... and it still didn't accept it. It's weird it worked fine in 3 but 4 it's stopped and their docs don't give much info. I'm going to have to email them for this nonsense. It makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

I think you needs use EmailAuthProviderID instead of FIREmailAuthProviderID. In the Firebase 4.0 no longer uses the FIR suffix.

Hope it help you :)

Comment: thanks for the help: I tried that (and a combination of other things) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: This isn't a correct answer but it is correct in content. *EmailAuthProviderID* is a string and not a class so it has no .credential function.