# Incorrect argument label in call (have 'email:password:', expected 'withEmail:password:')

Tags: ios, firebase, swift4, xcode9

I get this : Incorrect argument label in call (have 'email:password:', expected 'withEmail:password:')

While tryin to sign up user with email and password !!

[image: Codes]

I have looked at the firebase documents [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIREmailAuthProvider) But didn't have a clue of why not working

The error says[image: Error Msg] withEmail is invalid but it comes default with Firebase call function as

> EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail email: String, password:
>   String) -> AuthCredential

Found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125139/swift3-ios-firebase-firemailpasswordauthprovider-not-working/45130238#45130238) as well  But couldn't get it right !!

all my pods are updated[image]

Comment: don't post images of code , instead add your code.

Comment: What happens when you click on `Fix`? The error is quite clear. Hint: You cannot have two parameter labels for one parameter, read again what is *expected*.

Comment: have you tried writing piece of line by yourself? it might have shown some options while writing. You can see all required parameters, and what you need to provide i guess.

Comment: please check https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking

Answer (score 4):

I used the autocomplete functionality of Xcode and found that this is the function:

```
EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: String, password: String)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Authenticate with Firebase using Password-Based Accounts Use this reference
Use this for method instead.

For Create a password-based account

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
  // ...
}
```

And For Sign in a user with an email address and password

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
  // ...
}
```

At last For sign out a user

```
    let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
do {
  try firebaseAuth.signOut()
} catch let signOutError as NSError {
  print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
}
```

You can find documentation on this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth